# get length of hasMany relationship without triggering fetch

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

model:

```
DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', { async: true} ),

  hasComments: Ember.computed.gt('comments.length', 0)
});
```

payload:

```
{ 
  "id": "abcdefg",
  "title": "some cats are cool",
  "body": "",
  "comments: ["100", "101", "102"]
}
```

But the `hasComments` computed property triggers a fetch for each comment individually.. I don't want this :D

I know this works (avoids the fetch), but reaches into private API:

`hasComments: Ember.computed.gt('data.comments.length', 0)`

> ember.js 1.8.1
>
> ember-data 1.0.0-beta.11

Any other recommendations on achieving a computed property based off of the length

Comment: discussion on this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2431

Answer (score 6):

As of Ember Data 2.5 ([mentioned in release notes](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/05/03/ember-data-2-5-released.html#toc_code-ds-references-code)) there is a feature called `ds-references` which provides a way to check if if a hasMany relationship contains items or not without triggering a fetch for those items:

```
export default Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', { async: true} ),

  hasComments: Ember.computed('comments', function() {
    return this.hasMany('comments').ids().length > 0;
  })
});
```

See this working [in an Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c19e1acfb15626c0cc23a9d6b44f2803?openFiles=models.my-model.js%2C)

> The ds-references feature implements the references API as described
>   in RFC 57. References is a low level API to perform meta-operations on
>   records, has-many relationships and belongs-to relationships:
>
> - **get the current local data synchronously without triggering a fetch or producing a promise**
> - notify the store that a fetch for a given record has begun, and provide a promise for its result
> - similarly, notify a record that a fetch for a given relationship has begun, and provide a promise for its result
> - retrieve server-provided metadata about a record or relationship

Source: [Ember forum post](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/count-async-hasmany-without-loading/7751/7) and [Ember Data 2.5 release blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/05/03/ember-data-2-5-released.html#toc_code-ds-references-code)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned, that each comment was fetched individually. This can be avoided by setting [coalesceFindRequests](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#property_coalesceFindRequests) on the RestAdapter, if your backend supports this.

Yet, you'd still have one request too many. I don't think, that that can be avoided without some kind of dirty trick, but am open to learn from other answers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that tip.  Turns out there is  an open issue on github. Added comment to my question with direct link.

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was an easy way to do this. The simplest way I can think of is to override `extractHasMany` in your serializer and save a new property, `commentsCount`, on your model, eg:

models/post.rb:

```
DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment', { async: true} ),
  commentsCount: DS.attr('number'),

  hasComments: Ember.computed.gt('commentsCount', 0)
});
```

serializers/post.rb:

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  normalizeHash: {
    posts(hash) {
      hash.comments_count = hash.comments.length;
      return hash;
    }
  }
}
```

Be careful though, as the commentsCount property will not automatically recompute in this case when you add/remove comments. You could probably build a computed property that uses the actually comments instead of `commentsCount` if the comments are loaded.

Comment: thanks for sharing that work around! Everything I've uncovered points to code like yours. Another example I've run across,  https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/57#issuecomment-121008369